# Extra alignment in tabular array

Tags: latex, equation, tabular

I am trying to center one of the columns in a table and It says I have an extra column. The table also doesnt look correct i.e.

What it looks like:

```
F(t) F(s)
     u(t)
1/s
e    1/(s-a)
```

What I expect:

```
F(t) F(s)
u(t) 1/s
e    1/(s-a)
```

I think it is because I'm trying to insert an equation in the table but I'm not sure.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  % \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
  % \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.225\textwidth}  >{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}}
    \textbf{F(t)} & \textbf{F(s)} \\
    \(u(t)\) & \(\frac{1}{s}\) \\ 
    \(e^{at}\) & \(\frac{1}{s-a}\) \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah I posted on the wrong site, my bad. Werner's solution was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `\centering` to centre the column works, but it screws up the way `\\` is interpreted. A correction is included in the [`array` package](//ctan.org/pkg/array) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) after using alignment switches (like `\centering`, `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft`, etc) using `\arraybackslash`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{0.225\textwidth} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.15\textwidth} }
  $\mathbf{F(t)}$ & $\mathbf{F(s)}$ \\
  $u(t)$          &    $1 / s$      \\
  $e^{at}$        & $1 / (s - a)$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `>{\centering}`, then your code should compile as expected. Post a comment otherwise! Do you want any column to have centered contents?

Comment: ... but the OP explicitly mentioned they want to center a column, so removing `{\centering}` this against that.

Comment: True, I read and upvoted your answer. I did not know about the arraybackslash thing in here, thank you :) @Werner